# Why is my image so high on the page?

Tags: html

I have two buttons on a webpage, I am trying to make the Clear button be a little lower, to align with the Search button.  Why is the Clear button so high?

Here is a live example: http://www.davidjpotter.com/temp/test.php

[image]

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
  <img src="../images/button-clear.png">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: that is very poorly formed HTML.  You need closing tags for your, td and tr, and img is self closing

Comment: FYI you can just enter your code into stackoverflow, then highlight it and click the "code" button.

Comment: @Stefan: This isn't XML.  In HTML, `</td>` and `</tr>` are optional, so the HTML here is correct.  With that said, it helps people (and probably HTML parsers) a lot if you include them so no one has to guess whether you forgot a `</table>` tag or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<img src="../images/button-clear.png">
```

with this:

```
<img src="../images/button-clear.png" style="vertical-align: bottom; ">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's high because the default value of the `vertical-align` CSS property is `baseline`.  This applies to all elements with `display: inline`, which includes `<img>` elements.

Try instead setting it to `middle`:

```
<img src="../images/button-clear.png" style="vertical-align:middle" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with vertical alignment of the image which is an inline element and it's set to the baseline. Add 'vertical-align:bottom' to line them up.